# REACT- webpack compiled successfully, nothing shows in my browser

Tags: reactjs

This is my first attempt at creating a navbar using REACT. Although webpack compiled successfully, nothing shows in my browser.
Can I have some help please? This is the github repo for the project:

https://github.com/mah752/myportfolio
thank you,

Maryan

Answer (score 1):

I've cloned your repo and I see the following error in the browser:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app.css' in '/home/atota/development/myportfolio/src'
```

Open src/App.js and on line 10, you're doing the following import:

```
import "./app.css";
```

Whereas it should be:

```
import "./App.css";
```

Spoiler alert: after resolving this error, you'll see the following one in the Browser Dev Tools, related to your  component:

```
Uncaught Error: You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app.
```

I see you're using `react-router-dom`, I suggest you to take a look at the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial).

Comment: if you're going to reference the docs at least locate the correct part of the docs to show. That makes things much easier for OP to understand where to look.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I resolved the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

So this looks like it's something to do with the way you have implemented your routes. If you were too boot up your app and check the console you would see.

```
router.ts:5 Uncaught Error: You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app.
```

I have looked through your code and noticed that you have the routes in your nav bar as well as `index.js` so you're inserting `<Router>` inside another `<Router>` which breaking things. As `<App />` has your navbar which has the `<Router>` component also.

I would highly suggest going through this tutorial on React Router

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial

This will tell you how to implement your routers correctly and go over nested routes.

Also another tip. I noticed you have a lot of files in your components folder for example:

```
Project.js
Project.css
```

The best practice is to do create a directory for each component and create a css module file like so:

`components/projects/...` This would now look like

```
Project.module.css
Project.js
```

But going back to your issue, go through the link on React Router and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your tips! I have resolved the issue. I will also keep in mind the best practice advice for creating a directory for each component. Thank you :)